# Fetching random data from API on button click - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

When request is sent, response is always the same on page reload in Chrome but random (as it should be) in FireFox. On button click data is always the same after page reload.
I want to make a request on each button click to store different data in the state hook.

I also tried it in vanilla js and response is the same as well.

What is causing data to always be the same and not random on request?
I will store previously fetched data in the state but first have to figure out why is it always the same, I would appreciate any help as I'm new to these API calls and react as well.

App.js:

```js
import FetchColor from './common/FetchColor';
import ColorList from './components/ColorList';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [colorData, changeColor] = useState('');

  const changeColorHandler = () => {
    FetchColor(changeColor);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    FetchColor(changeColor);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button onClick={changeColorHandler}>
        {colorData ? colorData.tags[0].name : 'Change Color'}
      </button>
      <ColorList color={colorData} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

FetchColor.js:

```js
const FetchColor = async (changeColor) => {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.colr.org/json/color/random');
  const data = await response.json();
  const [color] = data.colors;
  changeColor(color);
};

export default FetchColor;
```

Vanilla JavaScript script.js:

```js
const fetchButton = document.getElementById('fetch-api');

fetchButton.addEventListener('click', fetchColorFunc);

async function fetchColorFunc() {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.colr.org/json/color/random');
  console.log(`Response: ${response}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
```

}

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in dev tools? Is it possible that the requests are cached? Try adding e.g., a random string or the current timestamp to the request (`?1234567`).

Comment: Have you tried logging the result of the fetch request? Then you can be sure that you are getting correct data back from the server. It could also be related to how react rerenders, redefines callbacks. Etc. Try useCallback

Comment: @SebastianRichner it's the same

Comment: @ZachSmith it's not just React, I also tried vanilla js, I just added code snippet above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to caching. If you look at the requests in Chrome's Network panel of the Developer Tools, you should see that the requests are cached and therefore always return the same value.

[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) optionally takes an init object containing custom settings that will be applied to the request, including [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache). For example, you can pass `cache: "no-cache"` or `cache: "no-store"` to bypass caching (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache) for details and differences) and you will get random results with each request.
See the following snippet as an example:

---

```js
async function fetchColorFunc() {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.colr.org/json/color/random', { cache: "no-cache" });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(`Data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
}

fetchColorFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome caches the request. You can see this, if you open the developer tools and check on the network tab. You will see, that all later calls are fetched from disk cache.

You can either add some random query to the url

```
const response = await fetch('https://www.colr.org/json/color/random?t='+Date.now());
```

or you can add a `cache-control` header with value `no-cache`.

```
const response = await fetch('https://www.colr.org/json/color/random', { headers : {"cache-control": "no-cache"}});
```

But that will trigger a preflight request and requires the server to allow CORS from your origin.

Comment: Both work!
Thank you for response, really appreciate it. :)